# Is there an Immutable dictionary type in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments, immutability

I want to define a function, which would have dictionary like parameter, e.g.:

```
def my_func(params={'skip': True}):
    print(params['skip'])
    params['skip'] = False
```

However if a mutable dictionary `dict()` is used - it gets created only once for a function. And modifications made to that dictionary are present during the next call.

```
my_func()  # prints True
my_func()  # prints False
```

Currently the only idea I have is to use tuple of key/value pairs, which can be converted into a dictionary, instead of providing dictionary like data.

```
def my_func(params=(('skip', True))):
    params = dict(params)
    print(params['skip'])
    params['skip'] = False
```

However, I would really like to avoid this explicit conversion to a dictionary.
My question is: Is there an Immutable dictionary alternative for `dict()` as there is `tuple()` for `list()`?

Comment: You could create a deepcopy of the dict that you then use in the function body. The `copy` module provides a deepcopy function for dicts.

Comment: Why do you not simply use proper function parameters with default arguments? `def my_func(skip=True)`

Comment: If `params` were immutable, what would you expect to be the result of `params['skip'] = False`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would avoid having every call to `func` using the default `params` share the same `dict` (which seems to be your issue):

```
def my_func(params=None):
    params = {'skip': True} if params==None else params
```

Comment: Shorter, nicer,
`params = params or {'skip': True}`